# Effect of Moving within the Feasible Region

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, affine-geometry

$f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a concave function with local maximum at $\mathbf{x}^*$ in a convex, closed feasible set $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Now consider a suboptimal point $\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{F}$. If we move from $\mathbf{x}$ in such a direction (within the feasible region) that

1) $\mathcal{L}_1$ norm of $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^*$ increases monotonically.

2) $\mathcal{L}_2$ norm of $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^*$ increases monotonically.

Does it mean $f\left(\mathbf{x}\right)$ will decrease in both of the above cases (considered independently)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** No. Consider $f(x,y) = -(x^2+9y^2)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The origin is the sole local and global maximum point of $f$. If we move from $(1,1)$ to $(3,0)$ along the line $x+2y-3=0$, the $L_1$ norm increases from $2$ to $3$ and the $L_2$ norms increases from $\sqrt{2}$ to $2$, yet $f(1,1)=-10<f(3,0)=-9$. If you plot a graph, you will see that $f$ increases monotonically at first, then attains the maximum value $-6.23$ at $(x,y)\approx(2.08,0.46)$ in the course of movement and then decreases monotonically to $-9$.

Comment: Thanks for the counter example. But the distance has to increase monotonically. In your example, the distance along the line from (0, 1) to (2, 0), the distance comes to minimum at (.4, .8) then it increases. So the path isn't admissible. I should have explained it in the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Barman Thanks for your comment. See my new edit.